# MYSQL Mass update row value url

Tags: php, mysqli

Okay so I have a client that wants to switch a website over to a different domain name. Only one problem. She has a ton of values stored in a database that contain her domain name. I feel like i'm just copying and pasting the prefix at this point. Is there a way that I can easily find values and replace the prefix from http://example.com/ to http://example2.com/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this,

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET DomainColumn = REPLACE (DomainColumn, 'http://example.com/', 'http://example2.com/')
WHERE DomainColumn LIKE '%example.com/%'
```